# Quebra de linha em JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou desenvolvendo uma tabela periodica completa e bonita para o curso. Porém na hora de implementar o jbutton ele me deixa colocar apenas um texto, nada de espaço, quebra de linha e outras frases em outras linhas, como seria uma tabela normal. Como faço para quebrar linhas no JButton? Exemplo:

```
1
  Ex
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
button.setText("<html>1<br>Ex</html>");
```

Componentes swing permitem que você [**insira textos como html**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) dentro deles. É uma solução, apesar de, particularmente, achar que essa forma, se usada com muito volume num código, o deixa de difícil leitura e manutenção.